# Updating CampaignMember Record via RESTful web service

Tags: apex, rest-api, force.com-sites, update, campaign-member

Also new at APEX and this is my first crack at it. I want to update some fields on the CampaignMember object when I catch a Webhook on a force.com site. I have the Webhook working, however I am having issues updating a record in the object.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myservice')

global class MyService {

@HttpGet

global static String doGet() {

String campId = RestContext.request.params.get('campId');
String email = RestContext.request.params.get('email');
String medium = RestContext.request.params.get('medium');
String source = RestContext.request.params.get('source');

String queriedCampaign = [SELECT ID FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignMember.CampaignID = :campId AND CampaignMember.Email = :email].ID;

CampaignMember.queriedCampaign.Medium__c = medium;
queriedCampaign.CampaignMember.Source__c = source;

update queriedCampaign.CampaignMember;  

}
}
```

I believe my query is correct, but struggling with the proper syntax to update the record. Thanks in advance for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Querying A Record

To update a record, you must first have a copy of a record in memory. This means you need a CampaignMember object to update:

```
CampaignMember queriedCampaign = [SELECT ID FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignID = :campId AND Email = :email LIMIT 1];
```

## Assignment

In general, you declare and assign values in the form of:

```
DataType variableName [= someValue];
```

Where `[= someValue]` is optional.

Examples:

```
Integer x = 5;
Integer y; // Has no value, a "null" value
```

## Query Fields

For queries, you don't generally use the `Object.Field` syntax, unless referring to a parent object (see query updated, above).

### Incorrect

```
SELECT CampaignMember.Email FROM CampaignMember
```

### Correct

```
SELECT Email FROM CampaignMember
SELECT Campaign.Name FROM CampaignMember
```

## Assignment (again)

Then, you can assign the values to that record:

```
queriedCampaign.Medium__c = medium;
queriedCampaign.Source__c = source;
```

Notice how this is in the form of:

```
variable.property = valueToAssign;
```

For simple variables, such as String or Integer, the assignment is in the form of:

```
variable = valueToAssign;
```

Example:

```
Integer x = 5;
Integer y;
y = x * 2; // Multiply x times 2, and place that value in y. x is still 5.
```

## DML Operations

Finally, to update the record, you:

```
update queriedCampaign;
```

Generically, DML is in the form of:

```
operation recordOrRecordList;
```

---

You'll find all of this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/) and on the [Apex trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) (and other trails there you can follow for free!).

Comment: Thanks so much! Jumping into Trailhead now. You = The Man.